# Edit components list in trac

Tags: trac

How to add/edit components list in trac. Where's the 'trac.ini' file found?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the appropriate admin permissions, you can use the Admin web interface to edit Components (URL `.../admin/ticket/components`).

`trac.ini` is in `<projectenv>/conf/trac.ini`.

Answer (score 4):

The component list is not stored in the .ini, but in the database.  Use the admin tab in the web interface (logged in as a user with `TRAC_ADMIN` or `TICKET_ADMIN` permissions) to manage your components.  OR, you can use the trac-admin commandline utility to add and remove components.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions to components are managed using the Trac Permissions (TICKET_VIEW, BROWSER_VIEW, etc ..).

However, components (and plug-ins) can be enabled and disabled via *trac.ini*.  Take a look at the [components](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#components-section) section of the TracIni documentation.